# Devise 3.0 after bundle update and registration stop working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I made bundle update for my project and devise stop working on it. Right now it says that email cant be blank - but it isnt. Can somebody tell my what is wrong and what change in devise 3.0?

Output in console for devise is:

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"L5182qPo2YonLhXfMbCXxXtvEHfM8YZMYr74pnPN8K0=", "user"=>{"name"=>"user_10", "email"=>"user_10@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Unpermitted parameters: name, email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end
```

For application_controller and devise working

Comment: remember to do it for the registration controller (`:account_update`) as well